# Using distortion co-efficients on a distorted image to un-distort

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

Given the distortion co-efficients **D = k1,k2,p1,p2,k3** of a pinhole model which is defined by radial and tangential distortion.
How to undistort an image with these co-efficients? 
I know about the **cv2.undistort()** function. Can anyone explain me how to implement the undistortion function to perform iterative minimization?

```
    # TODO: Iterative minimization required
    r2 = x_ * x_ + y_ * y_
    # Remove tangential distortion
    x_tangential = x_ - (2 * distort_coeffs[2] * x_ * y_ + distort_coeffs[3] * (r2 + 2 * x_ * x_))
    y_tangential = y_ - (distort_coeffs[2] * (r2 + 2 * y_ * y_) + 2 * distort_coeffs[3] * x_ * y_)
    # Remove radial distortion
    x = x_tangential / (1 + distort_coeffs[0] * r2 + distort_coeffs[1] * r2 * r2 + distort_coeffs[4] * r2 * r2 * r2)
    y = y_tangential / (1 + distort_coeffs[0] * r2 + distort_coeffs[1] * r2 * r2 + distort_coeffs[4] * r2 * r2 * r2)

    cam_coords_undistorted = torch.cat([x, y, ones], 1)
```

Comment: What is the question, exactly? One does not try to solve the poly equation (system, rather, unless p1 = p2 = 0) analytically. The OpenCV code finds numerical solution using an iterative algorithm.

Comment: @Francesco Callari I am interested in the procedure followed by opencv to undisort the image iteratively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two cases:

1. The distortion is purely radial (tangential coefficients p1, p2 = 0). The problem boils down to solving a polynomial equation of odd degree, and you want the smallest solution that is positive and real. Any equation solver algorithm will do, the adjoint method being a common choice. For pure radial, single-parameter distortion, in particular, you get a third-degree equation that can be solved analytically using Cardano's formula. Or you can use the recursion below.
2. General case, the distortion equations are coupled, and you need to solve an actual system of two coupled polynomial equations. You could pose the problem as one of minimizing the residual for a given tentative solution, but for this particular system of equations there is a shortcut available: the solution is a fixed point of the recursion induced by the distortion function itself. See equation (8) in Heikkila's old [paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2bbf/c8a84aaac5221e67a175dbaa3b6c32f6604d.pdf) for an explanation. The OpenCV code is loosely based on it.

Comment: Also given an image with 1392 x 512. Does the co-efficient change when we resize the image to 512x 256? The intrinsics are scaled appropriately to adapt to the new resolution. Opencv states it won#t change if aspect ratio is maintained.